# Converting an AML into Python - terms not within help

Tags: python, aml

I'm using an AML used for preprocessing required by the SPARROW model (https://www.usgs.gov/mission-areas/water-resources/science/sparrow-modeling-estimating-nutrient-sediment-and-dissolved?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects). I do not have ArcInfo Workstation, and my IT department does not have a copy either, nor are we able to download a copy. So the solution is to convert it to Python, however even for such a short script this has proven to be rather taxing. Part of the problem is that I do not recognise what all of the commands within the AML actually do (see script below).

```
/* Edit the pathname for the directory containing the ArcInfo reach coverage as necessary
&workspace A:\river_line

&DATA arc info
ARC
CALC $NM = 1
CALC $COMMA-SWITCH = -1
CALC $PRINTER-SIZE = 200

/* Edit the name of the aat as necessary
arc.aat
/* Edit the name of the attribute for the unique reach identifier
/* as necessary
SORT LINKNO
RESEL LINKNO LT 80000

/************************************
/* Output reach attributes for non-coastal reaches
/* Edit the path for the output file as necessary, but retain the
/* name reach.dat for the output file.
/* Edit attribute names as necessary.
/************************************
OUTPUT D:\sparrow\data\reach.dat INIT
PRINT LINKNO,FNODE#,TNODE#,DEMIAREA,FRAC,HUC2

ASEL/* Edit the aat file name as necessary (retain the # symbol)
SORT arc#
Q STOP
&END
&RETURN
```

For instance I do not know what: RESEL, LT, and ASEL means. Any idea?

Comment: Arc/Info, AML. Coverages, all require workstation, or at least a workstation license. ArcPy can work with coverages but will check for the license. No license no python. All this is doing selecting polylines (arcs) with a Linkno (field in attribute table) less than (LT) and saving it to a file (dat). So export it to a shapefile and in ArcMp or QGIS open the shapefile and select, edit and export.

Comment: Does SPARROW software require arcinfo to be installed?

Comment: `RESEL LINKNO LT 80000` -> update the selection to include rows where the "LINKNO" column is less than 80000 (just a guess)

Comment: That's not an AML script as much as it is an INFO script (wrapped in AML).This script is actually a bit frightening, since it intentionally corrupts the coverage contents and then uncorrupts it on the way out, when there were many less risky ways to achieve the same result.  The modern equivalent would be a DA SearchCursor with a `where_clause` and a `ORDER BY` in the `sql_clause`.

Comment: This script does not do much but, what it does do, by applying a select, reselect and sort on the INFO node data directly, could easily corrupt the data. I am not even sure that this output tracks given that shapefiles do not have the same node topology as the old ARC/INFO coverage model. It seems like a smoother track would be to spell out what you are wanting to accomplish here rather than trying to translate this dated script.

Comment: Thanks all. A note on this application: this is an AML provided for the purpose of preprocessing for the SPARROW model. There is absolutely no reference as to what the script does in the documentation, it simply states to run it to get it to work. Fortunately, the script is fairly simple so with thanks to klewis, this was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import arcpy

#  This should mimic your Arc/Info program as listed above.
#  You can convert an .e00 to a Coverage with,
#  C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.x\bin\import71.exe
#  The arc layer is an alias for the .aat (arc attribute table) on disk

coverage = r'C:\Users\heisenburg\Downloads\e00\hydroCov\arc'

dat = r'C:\Users\heisenburg\Downloads\e00\hydro.dat'

f = open(dat, 'w')

where_clause = 'LINKNO < 80000'
sql_clause = ('','Order by LINKNO Asc')

fields = ['Linkno','fnode#','tnode#','DEMIAREA','FRAC','HUC2']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(coverage, fields, where_clause,"","",sql_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        output_record = '{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5])
        f.write(output_record)

f.close()
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. I had to make a small modification as it didn't seem to be sorting by LINKNO for some reason, so I used sorted() instead, which worked a treat. Anyway, I'm pretty sure this is what is necessary for the model, fingers crossed.